# Wrong Instagram Feed Bug

Tags: javascript, jquery, oauth, instagram, instagram-api

I am using this plugin:http://www.jqueryscript.net/social-media/jQuery-Plugin-To-Display-Instagram-Photos-On-Your-Web-Page-Instagram-Lite.html

When I set up my username and `client-ID`, it pulls photos from the wrong feed, for which I don't even have access (it pulls from *helaspamexico*, but instead it should be pulling from *helaspa* -> I am logged in to this and have generated *client-ID* for this)... Has anyone experienced something similar?

```js
/*!

Name: Instagram Lite
Dependencies: jQuery
Author: Michael Lynch
Author URL: http://michaelynch.com
Date Created: January 14, 2014
Licensed under the MIT license

*/

;(function($) {

    $.fn.instagramLite = function(options) {
    
     // return if no element was bound
  // so chained events can continue
  if(!this.length) { 
   return this; 
  }
        
        // define plugin
        plugin = this;
        
        // define default parameters
        plugin.defaults = {
            username: null,
            clientID: null,
            limit: null,
            list: true,
            videos: false,
            urls: false,
            captions: false,
            date: false,
            likes: false,
            comments_count: false,
            max_id: null,
            load_more: null,
            error: function() {},
            success: function() {}
        }
        
        // vars
        var s = $.extend({}, plugin.defaults, options),
         el = $(this);

        var getMaxId = function(items) {
     
      // return id of last item
      return items[items.length-1].id;
     };
     
     var formatCaption = function(caption) {
     
      var words = caption.split(' '),
       newCaption = '';
      
      for(var i = 0; i < words.length; i++) {
       
       var word;
       
       if(words[i][0] == '@') {
        var a = '<a href="http://twitter.com/'+words[i].replace('@', '').toLowerCase()+'" target="_blank">'+words[i]+'</a>';
        word = a;
       } else if(words[i][0] == '#') {
        var a = '<a href="http://twitter.com/hashtag/'+words[i].replace('#', '').toLowerCase()+'" target="_blank">'+words[i]+'</a>';
        word = a;
       } else {
        word = words[i]
       }
 
       newCaption += word + ' ';
      }
     
      return newCaption;
      
     };
     
     var loadContent = function() {
 
      // if client ID and username were provided
         if(s.clientID && s.username) {
         
          // for each element
          el.each(function() {
          
           var el = $(this);
          
           // search the user
           // to get user ID
           $.ajax({
            type: 'GET',
            url: 'https://api.instagram.com/v1/users/search?q='+s.username+'&client_id='+s.clientID+'&callback=?',
            dataType: 'jsonp',
            success: function(data) {
  
             if(data.data.length) {
              
              // define user namespace
              var thisUser = data.data[0];
              
              // construct API endpoint
        var url = 'https://api.instagram.com/v1/users/'+thisUser.id+'/media/recent/?client_id='+s.clientID+'&count='+s.limit+'&callback=?';
        
        // concat max id if max id is set
        url += (s.max_id) ? '&max_id='+s.max_id : '';
   
              $.ajax({
               type: 'GET',
               url: url,
               dataType: 'jsonp',
               success: function(data) {
                
                // if success status
                if(data.meta.code === 200 && data.data.length) {
           
                 // for each piece of media returned
                 for(var i = 0; i < data.data.length; i++) {
                 
                  // define media namespace
                  var thisMedia = data.data[i],
                   item;
                  
                  // if media type is image or videos is set to false
                  if(thisMedia.type === 'image' || !s.videos) {
                  
                   // construct image
                   item = '<img class="il-photo__img" src="'+thisMedia.images.standard_resolution.url+'" alt="Instagram Image" data-filter="'+thisMedia.filter+'" />';

                   // if url setting is true
                   if(s.urls) {
                   
                    item = '<a href="'+thisMedia.link+'" target="_blank">'+item+'</a>';
                    
                   }
                   
                   if(s.captions || s.date || s.likes || s.comments_count) {
                    item += '<div class="il-photo__meta">';
                   }
                   
                   // if caption setting is true
                   if(s.captions && thisMedia.caption) {
                   
                    item += '<div class="il-photo__caption" data-caption-id="'+thisMedia.caption.id+'">'+formatCaption(thisMedia.caption.text)+'</div>';
                    
                   }
                   
                   // if date setting is true
                   if(s.date) {
                   
                    var date = new Date(thisMedia.created_time * 1000),
                     day = date.getDate(),
               month = date.getMonth() + 1,
               year = date.getFullYear(),
               hours = date.getHours(),
               minutes = date.getMinutes(),
               seconds = date.getSeconds();
               
              date = month +'/'+ day +'/'+ year;
                   
                    item += '<div class="il-photo__date">'+date+'</div>';
                    
                   }
                   
                   // if likes setting is true
                   if(s.likes) {
                   
                    item += '<div class="il-photo__likes">'+thisMedia.likes.count+'</div>';
                    
                   }
                   
                   // if caption setting is true
                   if(s.comments_count && thisMedia.comments) {
                   
                    item += '<div class="il-photo__comments">'+thisMedia.comments.count+'</div>';
                    
                   }
                   
                   if(s.captions || s.date || s.likes || s.comments_count) {
                    item += '</div>';
                   }

                  }
                  
                  if(thisMedia.type === 'video' && s.videos) {
                   
                   if(thisMedia.videos) {
                   
                    var src;
                   
                    if(thisMedia.videos.standard_resolution) {
                    
                     src = thisMedia.videos.standard_resolution.url;
                     
                    } else if(thisMedia.videos.low_resolution) {
                    
                     src = thisMedia.videos.low_resolution.url;
                     
                    } else if(thisMedia.videos.low_bandwidth) {
                    
                     src = thisMedia.videos.low_bandwidth.url;
                     
                    }
                    
                    item = '<video poster="'+thisMedia.images.standard_resolution.url+'" controls>';
                    
                    item += '<source src="'+src+'" type="video/mp4;"></source>';
                    
                    item += '</video>';
                    
                   }
                  }
                  
                  // if list setting is true
                  if(s.list && item) {
                  
                   // redefine item with wrapping list item
                   item = '<li class="il-item" data-instagram-id="'+thisMedia.id+'">'+item+'</li>';
                  }

                  // append image / video
                  if(item !== '') {
                   el.append(item);
                  }
                 }
                 
                 // set new max id
                 s.max_id = getMaxId(data.data);
                 
                 // execute success callback
                 s.success.call(this);
                
                } else {
                 
                 // execute error callback
                 s.error.call(this, data.meta.code, data.meta.error_message);
                 
                }
               
               },
               error: function() {
               
                // recent media ajax request failed
                // execute error callback
                s.error.call(this);
               }
              });
 
             } else {
             
              // error finding username
              // execute error callback
        s.error.call(this);
              
             }
            },
            error: function() {
            
             // search username ajax request failed
             // execute error callback
       s.error.call(this);
             
            }
           });
          
          });
         
         } else {
         
          // username or client ID were not provided
       // execute error callback
    s.error.call(this);
         };
     }
     
     // bind load more click event
        if(s.load_more){
         $(s.load_more).on('click', function(e) {
          e.preventDefault();
          loadContent();
         });
        }
     
     // init
        loadContent(); 
    }
    
})(jQuery);
```

```html
<ul class="instagram"></ul>
<a href="#" class="instagram-more" title="">Load more</a>
<br clear="all">

<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

  <script>
          
          // Wait untill everything loads
          $(window).load(function(){

   $('.instagram').instagramLite({
    username: 'helaspa',
    clientID: 'ecdadd6520c04f5b8ae8bfdc888dd59c',
    urls: true,
    limit: 10,
    load_more: '.instagram-more',
    captions: false,
    likes: false,
    comments_count: false,
    success: function() {
    
     console.log('The request was successful!');
    },
    error: function(errorCode, errorMessage) {
    
     console.log('There was an error');
    
     if(errorCode && errorMessage) {
    
      alert(errorCode +': '+ errorMessage);
     
     }
     
    }
   });            
            
            
            
            });
  

   
   
  
  </script>
```

Comment: It isn't really a bug, but something related to Instagram API results, I check ed the plugin source code for something I was expecting to see which is [linked to this problem directly](http://stackoverflow.com/a/33428613/2151050). Turns out I was wrong in my theory. Can you link can you create a fiddle for your problem trying to re-produce the problem?

Comment: I included the source code

Comment: Use this http://www.jqueryscript.net/demo/jQuery-Plugin-To-Display-Instagram-Photos-On-Your-Web-Page-Instagram-Lite/src/instagramLite.js 
The developer has added some additional code to match the username. The plugin you posted is missing that conditional :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are looking for a bad but quick solution, just put a '$' on the end of your username. The result of the API call will have your result first (by dumb luck) so the library will work.

The library you are using is not parsing the result of the query API correctly. The query API returns results for usernames similar to your query and doesn't filter results that are the wrong username.

Really, you should submit a patch to the library to use an API other than search: https://instagram.com/developer/endpoints/users/

Here is the bad the function:
https://github.com/michael-lynch/instagram-lite/blob/master/src/instagramLite.js#L95